# Jssc Flow Control Xon

Tags: java, arduino, usb, flow-control, jssc

I'm using Jssc for an arduino based application. It works great. I'm able to send and receive.
But I'm having issues with the XonXoff flow control.

Does Jssc automattically stop sending when the Xoff char is received ??

Of course, I used

```
serialPort.setFlowControlMode(SerialPort.FLOWCONTROL_XONXOFF_IN | SerialPort.FLOWCONTROL_XONXOFF_OUT);
```

Or do I have to listen to the received data in my own app, and watch for Xon and Xoff myself, and then stop sending ?

In my case it seems that the Xon and Xoff char go into the serial event RXCHAR despite flow control being enabled. I do receive Xon and Xoff char in my software.
Is this normal ? Is this related to the USB to COM driver ?

I'm running under Windows 7, with the Arduino connected as USB.

Thanks,